# Get value each input with the same name inside table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, html-table

I have a table and the tbody is populate dynamically from data response from node.js. That is why when I create the input the name and id stays equals in the all rows.

Table:

```
<table id="tblNotas">
    <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Column</th>
          <th>Column</th>
          <th>Input</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <% alunos.forEach(function(aluno) { %>
       <tr>
          <td><label>Some text</label></td>
          <td><label>Some text</label></td>                             
          <td>
            <input id="txtNota" name="txtNota" type="number" min="0.0" max="10" step="0.01">
          </td>
       </tr>
       <% }); %>                        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In JavaScript or JQuery, how I get the value of the input `txtNota` of each row?

Comment: Since "txtNota" is an ID, its impossible to use it more than once.

Comment: You should use classes instead of ids here. Ids are supposed to be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('input[name="txtNota"]').each(function(key,val){
      alert(val.value)
})
```

Do read about selectors though.This can be extended to class or just about any html attribute.
reference: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have class instead of ID (for your inputs), you could do something like that :

```
function getValues() {
    var values = new Array();
    $('#tblNotas tbody .txtNota').each(function (i,e) {
        values.push({
            $(e).val()
        })
    });
    return values;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which template engine you are using here, but you should be able to do something like this

```
<% alunos.forEach(function(aluno) { %>
     <tr>
        <td><label>Some texto</label></td>
        <td><label>Some texto</label></td>                             
        <td>
            <input id="<%= aluno.id %>" name="txtNota" type="number" min="0.0" max="10" step="0.01">
        </td>
     </tr>
<% }); %>
```

Basically, the idea is to grab the id from the object you are iterating over and pass it in the ID of your DOM element, e.g. each input.

Comment: With express, you can use different template engines, like jade, mustache, handlebars or ejs (your code is looking a lot like ejs). Given your aluno objects have a `id` key with a string-like value, you could try my updated answer.